# matplotlib nice plot , who knows the scheme used?

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-scheme

May somebody know which is the scheme of color used in this post for the example plot ? this blue magenta, green ? which kind of style it is ??

[image]

**EDIT** ah ok I thought that was a known schemes

Comment: Match the colors from this website: https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html

Comment: sorry which one of this ?

Comment: You will have to match them and find for yourself. It's not a big task. Take a `sin` function and plot it in different colors which looks similar to the one you want and compare.

Comment: looks nice ! I'm interesting too!

Comment: The colors are ["#7aa0c4","#ca82e1" ,"#8bcd50"] (as defined in a code snippet from the post where you got the plots from).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shown plot comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot/43439132#43439132). The colors in use are just hardcoded and do not belong to any official color scheme. The line colors are

```
["#7aa0c4", "#ca82e1", "#8bcd50"]
```

The background color is

```
"#f6f9fd"
```

The complete script to generate the plot is also available [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10079#issuecomment-357090037).

In general, if you like to reproduce the colors from some image you find it's often easiest to use a [color picker](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/eyedroppers-color-pickers-for-designers/).

Since I invented this "scheme", you may of course ask how I would imagine it to continue for more colors. A quick guess would be the following:

```
["#7aa0c4", "#ca82e1", "#8bcd50", "#df9f53", "#64b9a1", "#745ea6", "#db7e76"]
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cols = ["#7aa0c4", "#ca82e1", "#8bcd50", "#df9f53", "#64b9a1",
        "#745ea6", "#db7e76"]

plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"] = plt.cycler("color", cols)

x = np.linspace(0,4*np.pi, 101)
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
for i in range(7):
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(x)-0.2*i)
    ax2.plot(x, np.sin(x-np.pi*i/7))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you !!! unfortunately is not a scheme :( because I really like the first three and was wonderful find the others chosen to be nice as this three

Comment: I updated the answer with what I might think is a good idea for extending this scheme.

Comment: I'm sorry if it is out of topic .. but may you also advice about a grayscale scheme ?

Comment: The scheme shown here is not well suited to be used on grey scale because most of the variance happens in the hue, but with similar saturation and lightness. For grayscale, best stick to the default one, i.e. `plt.style.use("grayscale")`.